# Oracle 21c XE, need install/enable JServer JAVA Virtual Machine, but ORA-00904

Tags: oracle, java

In Oracle 21c XE, I need install/add JServer JAVA Virtual Machine. When I try to install it, there is a problem, exactly `ORA-00904: "PSU_VER": invalid identifier`.

```
SQL> @?/javavm/install/initjvm.sql;

...

drop role dbjavascript
create role dbjavascript
grant dbjavascript to sys

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

create or replace java system
begin if initjvmaux.startstep('CREATE_JAVA_SYSTEM') then
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "PSU_VER": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at "SYS.INITJVMAUX", line 28
ORA-06512: at line 5


Disconnected from Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0
```

Now it is in `LOADING' state.

```
VERSION                STATUS
------------------------------ --------------------------------------------
JServer JAVA Virtual Machine
21.0.0.0.0             LOADING
```

Where is the catch please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The catch is that 21c XE comes with all features preinstalled including "JServer JAVA Virtual Machine", yet for some unknown reason you wanted to install it manually, which messed it up.

At this point I would not bother, just reinstall and use the database as it gets created automatically. Express Edition is different and not supported officially, the scripts used for other editions may not work properly.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer. Catch was that I used already installed folder, so I downloaded installation from oracle link, converted rpm -> deb, extract it and used correct install package.